# Python infinite recursion with generators

Tags: python, recursion, iterator

I'm trying to wrap my head around python generators and as a result, I'm trying to print infinitely nested objects using yield, but I find that I still get problems with blowing out the stack.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to yield and print each item as it comes along but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
class Parent:    
    def __init__(self, name, child=None):
        self._name = name
        self._child = child

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def get_child(self):
        return self._child

    def set_child(self, child):
        self._child = child

    def __iter__(self):
        next_child = self._child.get_child()
        if not next_child:
            raise StopIteration            
        else:
            self._child = next_child
            yield next_child

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s has %s" % (self._name, self._child)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Parent("child")
    p2 = Parent("child", p1)
    p1.set_child(p2)

    for t in p1:
        print t
```

Comment: If you read the traceback, you will note that the error is caused by `print t`, therefore via `Parent.__str__`, not `__iter__`. You have set this up yourself - `p1` is a child of `p2`, which is a child of `p1`, which is a child of `p2`, which...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code, as noted by jonrsharpe, is due to the `__str__` function, which tries to return:

```
child has child has child has child has child has ...
```

You probably mean:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s has %s" % (self._name, self._child.get_name()) 
    # return 'child has child'
```

Also, `__iter__` should be a generator function. Generator functions need to contain a loop in order to continually produce values. So it should be something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    next_child = self._child.get_child()
    while next_child:            
        yield next_child
        next_child = next_child.get_child()
    # When the function ends, it will automatically raise StopIteration
```

With the modifications, your code prints endless lines of `child has child`.

See also [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) for more information about generator functions.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite recursion is happening at `__str__` function. It has nothing to do with the `__iter__` function.

when you do `print t`, it executes `t._child.__str__` which in turn executes `t._child._child.__str__` and so forth.

try changing the `__str__` function definition to something simple like  `return self._name` and you won't get a recursion depth exceeded error